# What is wrong with my Jasmine code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Here is my code written in jasmine and I am watching the tutorial here: [Jasmine-jquery tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Huh44nsZTw&index=12&list=PLOxOmO43E6Jt0SruKGxtZs-W3PJN90G_a)

Jasmine:

```
describe('example', function() {
var elem;

beforeEach(function() {
    elem = $('<div id="container"><p>Hello World</p></div>');
});

it('allows to search css', function() {
    expect(elem).toBeMatchedBy('#container');
    expect(elem).toHaveText('Hello World');
    expect(elem).toHaveHtml('<p></p>');
});
```

Here is my SpecRunner HTML head:

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.3.4</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
  <!-- include source files here... -->

  <script src="src/yeahboy.js"></script>
  <script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="src/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- include spec files here... -->

  <script src="spec/exampleSpec.js"></script>

</head>
```

Am I missing something here? Here is my error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must replace '#containers' to '#container'.

Comment: edited. I found out that `toBe` is not working. I have the `toHaveHtml` but it return me the error above. This is weird.